# Django Migrate - change charfield to datetimefield

Tags: django, django-models, migration

I have a charfield in a model that I wanted to change to Datetimefield.

From

```
days = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

To

```
days = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

But when I using the migrate command, it gives me this error.

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "days" cannot be cast to
>   type timestamp with time zone

I am using Django 1.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's approach to timezone handling is to convert all `datetimes` to UTC and then store them in the database without any timezone information. Apparently your `CharFields` include a timezone field.

One approach would be to edit the migrations file produced by `makemigrations` and insert a [`RunPython`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) command as the first operation. Use that to convert your `CharFields` to a string UTC version without timezones. That might look something like this:

```
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime
from django.utils import timezone

days_aware = parse_datetime(days)
days_utc = days_aware.astimezone(timezone.utc)
days_naive = days_utc.replace(tzinfo=None)
days = str(days_naive)
```

Alternatively, instead of changing the string representation, you could instead create the `DateTimeField` as a new field (say `days_dt`); do a `RunPython` data migration where you convert the string to a datetime (`days_dt = parse_datetime(days)`); delete the `days` field; and rename `days_dt` to `days`. That would also work and would leave Django in charge of representing datetimes at the database level.

Comment: I have tried the second option. Since it is still at development stage and the value in `days` doesn't matter. So I completely delete the `days` field and add a new `new_days` field, but still I got the  `column "days" cannot be cast to type timestamp with time zone`

Comment: @dev-jim: Did you delete the old migration file? Anyway, if you don't care about preserving data you can make this even easier. Just delete the field, run `makemigrations`, and then re-add `days` as a `DateTimeField` and run `makemigrations` again.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but probably you should do something like this posts explain:
[South migrate DateField to IntegerField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413806/south-migrate-datefield-to-integerfield) or [Django south: changing field type in data migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600056/django-south-changing-field-type-in-data-migration)

Comment: dev-jim is using django 1.7, so `south` isn't a option here for migration